How to correctly embed an iframe in Divi Theme?
I need to implement a live demo of one of our products on the company website.
Fortunately, our devs already made a display webpage that does exactly that and is controllable with the keyboard, so technically I should be able to embed this webpage in my site.
My issue is that I can't figure out how to resize it properly, I'm new to Divi and HTML in general. I have to do it this way because this webpage is a dev tool for us and I'm not supposed to share the URL (which is why I'm not doing a redirect to the page)...If someone could explain what I'm doing wrong, would be super helpful.
First I add a code module to the visual builder and type something like this :
<iframe src="https://url.com"></iframe>
It works but it's tiny. Using the sizing options for the module/row doesn't seem to do anything. I get that I should probably specify the sizing requirements but I don't know how to format my code for Divi and I couldn't find much about this.
The image ratio is 16:9
Thanks in advance ><

<div class="custom-iframe" style="position: relative; width: 100%; height: 0; padding-bottom: 56.25%;">
<iframe src="https://www.sites.com" style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%;" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

To embed an iframe in the Divi Theme, you'll need to adjust the iframe width and height attributes directly in the code module, add a Code Module in the Divi Builder where you want to add the iframe. You need to add the width and height to maintains the 16:9 aspect ratio.
